# Run M-x-git-gutter:clear when opening or switching to a buffer and saving a buffer

Tags: emacs

I am using [Emacs Live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live) which includes `git-gutter.el`. The problem is that it does not play well-with `linum-mode`. The issue is fixed when running <kbd>M-x</kbd> `git-gutter:clear`. I would like to include in my `init.el` a function that will execute `git-gutter:clear` whenever I switch to an existing buffer or open a new one. I also would like it to run when saving a buffer (via <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>). Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.  Most of us are used to seeing `M-x name-of-function` without a `-` between `M-x` and `name-of-function`

Comment: FYI git-gutter-fringe works with linux-mode. https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter-fringe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun user2475612-forward-window ()
  (interactive)
    (other-window 1)
    (git-gutter:clear) )

(defun user2475612-backward-window ()
  (interactive)
    (other-window -1)
    (git-gutter:clear) )

(add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook (lambda ()
  (git-gutter:clear) ))

(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (git-gutter:clear) ))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda ()
  (git-gutter:clear) ))
```

---

Here is a link to the documentation that deals with the standard hooks that are included in Emacs:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html